# Jquery Mobile : Is it possible to Open data-role="page" as Popup?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to open a new page as popup. I google it but not able to find answer.

Is Possible to do like that ??

Any Other Method to like that..I search all the Jquery mobile Doc. but not able to find any thing.

Here is my Code::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jquery Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <h1> Jquery Open Page in PopUp Examples</h1>

        <a href="#" id="open_popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window"> Open Page in PopUp </a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="Header">
            <p>
                PopUp
            </p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>
                Content Page ??
            </h2>

            <p>
                This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and data-rel="dialog" attribute.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="Footer">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Sounds Good </a>
            <a href="#foo" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"> Cancel </a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, it cant be done, at least in jQuery Mobile versions < 1.4. Popup as it is MUST be part of the page DIV and as such it can't be accessed outside of a page.

There is another solution, you can replace your second page div with data-role="popup" and place it inside a first page DIV, it would look like this:

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/103/

### HTML :

```
<div data-role="page">
    <h1> Jquery Open Page in PopUp Examples</h1>
    
    <a href="#popupExample" id="open_popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window"> Open Page in PopUp </a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupExample">
        <div data-role="header"class="ui-content">
            <p>
                PopUp
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>
                Content Page ??
            </h2>
            
            <p>
                This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and data-rel="dialog" attribute.
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Sounds Good </a>
            <a href="#foo" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"> Cancel </a>
        </div>
    </div>         
</div>
```

You will need to play with a CSS to make it look nicer.

Other solution would be to wait for jQuery Mobile 1.4 which will allow for popup to be placed outside page DIV, so you can share it among several pages. Unfortunately jQuery Mobile is in alpha state and this feature is still not working correctly.

Comment: Thats grate. Thanks you very much. And yhh Example you mention here that works in my case.Thanks again.